# Android Gradle stop dependencies' tests from running

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a project which I am using Android Gradle 1.1 and Android Studio 1.1. I have 2 modules (A, which is dependent on B). The relevant parts of A's build.gradle file looks like so:

```
dependencies {
  compile project(':B') // the bad line
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
  testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.4'
}
```

However this has side effect of running the unit tests within B when I run the tests for A. I've tried a number of exclude syntaxes - none of them seem to stop B's unit tests from running unexpectedly!